# How do you detect a USB connection in Android MTP device?

Tags: android

I need to be able to detect USB connection on a MTP based Android device, that is when it is plugged in and disconnected.  Here is my current relevant code which is based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.waracle.ncr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature 
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"
        />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>             
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
                <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
                <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>     

    </application>

</manifest>
```

device_filter.xml. I have tried this with no values and with values I found getting all usb devices connected using the UsbManager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device
        vendor-id="5401" product-id="32"
        />
</resources>
```

In my onCreate i register the Broadcast Receiver.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
```

and here is the Broadcast Receiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {    
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Test broadcastreceiver Received something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

This should give me a toast if anything is received by it, nothing ever happens.

I have looked around for solutions but everything I find that works is UMS based.  It would be great if anyone could help with this, thanks.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?